# test kitchen i want to write node attributes and want to search in node serach

Tags: node.js, chef-infra, test-kitchen

In test kitchen i am trying to search nodes  but it is not giving any output

cookbook/test/integration/nodes

Json file 
{
        "id": "hive server",
        "chef_type": "node",
        "environment": "dev",
        "json_class": "Chef::Node",
        "run_list": [],
        "automatic": {
                "hostname": "test.net",
                "fqdn": "127.0.0.1",
                "name": "test.net",
                "ipaddress": "127.0.0.1",
                "node_zone": "green",
                "roles": []

```
    },

    "attributes": {
            "hiveserver": "true"
    }
```

}

Recipe

```
  hiveNodes = search(:node, "hiveserver:true AND environment:node.environment AND node_color:node["node_color"])



#hiveserverList = ""
#hiveNodes.each |hnode| do
#    hiveserverList += hnode
#end



#file '/tmp/test.txt' do
#  content '#{hiveserverList}'
#end
```

Comment: cookbook/test/integration/nodes


Json file { "id": "hive server", 
"chef_type": "node", 
"environment": "dev", 
"json_class": "Chef::Node", 
"run_list": [], 
"automatic":
 { "hostname": "test.net", 
"fqdn": "127.0.0.1", 
"name": "test.net", 
"ipaddress": "127.0.0.1", 
"node_zone": "green", 
"roles": []
    },

    "attributes": {
            "hiveserver": "true"
    }
}
Recipe
  hiveNodes = search(:node, "hiveserver:true AND environment:node.environment AND node_color:node["node_color"])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node search is giving nothing in test kitchen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543383/node-search-is-giving-nothing-in-test-kitchen)