# node search is giving nothing in test kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

No output from search in test kitchen

Throwing error  check the recipe and suggest me some details

Node JSON file

```
{
    "id": "cldb",
    "chef_type": "node",
    "json_class": "Chef::Node",
    "run_list": [],
    "automatic": {
        "hostname": "cldb.net",
        "fqdn":"127.0.0.1",
        "name": "cldb.net",
        "ipaddress": "127.0.0.1",
        "roles": [],
        "cldb" : true
    }
}
```

Recipe

---

```
cldbNodes = search(:node, "cldb:true")

cldb = "#{cldbNodes["fqdn"]}"

file '/tmp/test.txt' do
    content "#{cldb}"
end
```

Comment: How do you have your kitchen.yml config set up and what path is the node JSON file in?

Comment: ---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  #nodes_path:        test/integration/nodes
  environments_path: test/integration/default/environments
  client_rb:
    environment: test

  always_update_cookbooks: true

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: centos-7.2

suites:
  - name: nodesearch
    run_list:
      - recipe[nodesearch-cookbook::nodesearch_mapr]

Comment: `driver:
              name: vagrant
           provisioner:
              name: chef_zero
             environments_path: test/integration/default/environments
             client_rb:
              environment: test
               verifier:
name: inspec
platforms:
- name: centos-7.2
suites:
- name: nodesearch
run_list:
- recipe[nodesearch-cookbook::nodesearch_mapr]`

Comment: nodes_path:        test/integration/nodes

Comment: Okay, and what is the full path to the JSON file?

Comment: /cookbook/test/integration/nodes/cldb.json

Comment: Does it work if you do `cldbNodes.first['fqdn']` instead? A search normally returns an array, not a single object.

Comment: `cldbNodes = search(:node, "cldb:true")

cldb = "cldbNodes['fqdn']"

file '/tmp/test.txt' do
    content "#{cldb}"
end`

Comment: out put is   cldbNodes['fqdn']

Comment: In file  output is  cldbNodes['fqdn']

Comment: Yes, that's a string not a Ruby code expression. If you are unfamiliar with Ruby syntax you may need to learn that before working with Chef.

Comment: I need array only

Comment: cldb = "#{cldbNodes['fqdn']}[0]"          i learned ruby

Comment: Again, `cldbNodes` is an array so you want `cldb = cldbNodes[0]['fqdn']` or `cldb = cldbNodes.first['fqdn']`

Comment: Sorry       `#cldbList = Array.new()
#cldbNodes.each  do |cldb|
#    cldbList += cldb
#    i +=1
#end`

Comment: commented this  part forgot

Answer (score 0):

To summarize from the comments above, `search(...)` returns an array so you need to get a specific element, usually the first, before you can access node data.

Using the example above, it would be something like:

```
cldbNodes = search(:node, "cldb:true")

cldb = cldbNodes.first["fqdn"]

file '/tmp/test.txt' do
    content cldb
end
```

Comment: `cldbNodes = search(:node, "node_color:green")


cldbList = ""
cldbNodes.each  do |cldb|
    cldbList += cldb
end

cldb1 = cldbList[1]['hostname']


file '/tmp/test.txt' do
  content "#{cldb1}"
end`

Comment: Now issue is cldbList += cldb

Comment: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass  for

Comment: i = 0
cldbList = ""
cldbNodes.each  do |cldb|
    cldbList += cldb[i]['hostname']
   i +=1
end

Comment: i want to save array of cldbNodes['hostname'] in to individual variable